# february 6 2013 - end of custom actions, meaning end of reposting to walls?

Tags: facebook

February 6, 2013

The following change will go into effect on February 6th, 2013:
End of custom actions for content consumption 
We will no longer show Custom Open Graph actions that were published simply by a user consuming content. If you own one of these actions and it was previously approved, you will have received an email from us. Developers should stop publishing these actions as doing so will return an error starting February 6th. The only actions that can be published upon a user simply consuming content are built-in actions.

---

my custom action is to post to a users wall even when he is offline , i can repost a status update whenever i want. With the february 6th change , i believe i won't have the ability to repost to a users wall anymore, does anyone have an idea if there would be an alternative to be able to repost to a users wall? such as the feed dialog or login dialog ? will i have the ability to repost to a users wall after getting their token? please help , thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

with the february 6th (and following) updates, you won't be able to post on a user's wall if he is offline, because the `offline_access`authorization is already deprecated.
What you have to do now is take your users' access tokens, exchange them for a long term access token (lasts a couple of months if I don't go wrong) and use that for your posts.

May I know what do you mean by "repost on a user's wall"? What are you sharing? If it's a link or a message (status update) and similar things, it'll work (it's working for me), but you have to handle the moment when the access token expires. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem since posting on a users wall is not considered a custom action. 
Actions are special "interactions" that a users can perform in your app, for example if you define a 'watch' action then your application can post stuff like 'John watched a Titanic on your movie app' to the users wall. To use actions they must be manually defined for each application and go through an approval process.

To documentation for actions can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-action-type/